# How to changed normal nested css to styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have this  **CSS** styles which I want to change to **styled-components** in react:

```
.movie-page .movie-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto 60px auto;
}

.movie-page .movie-details h1 {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.movie-page .movie-details h1 span {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: #bbb;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

I'm a bit confused how does the tags nesting work. I'm doing this with styled-components:

```
const MovieDetails = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto 60px auto;

  h1 {
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }

  h1 span {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    color: #bbb;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
`;
```

Does this code seem to be ok? My **h1** tag looks like **p** tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to select like that. Bt you can also do like the following which will look neater:

```
const MovieDetailsHeader = styled.h1 `
   line-height: 1.5em;
   span {
        font-size: inherit;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        color: #bbb;
        line-height: inherit;
    }
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know why the h1 tag shows up as p tag if I do not specify it as `font-size: 2em` ?

Comment: Show me the react code for that. Also, if you think any answers where helpful, do not forget to upvote it